# When trying to preprocess view fields why does hook_preprocess_views_view_fields not always get called?

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I'm currently preprocessing a view to rewrite fields based on some other logic. We basically want paragraph content to link to the parent that's using it. We're using search api and search api solr so we have to index a lot of entities we might not actually display as pages.

Currently i have the following preprocess

```
    function centers_search_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
        // return early if not the correct view.
        if($vars['view']->name !== 'search_solr') {
            return;
        }

        // only rewrite urls of page attachments. Currently all are listed but
        // it's possible we won't need to handle all of them.
        $content_types = array(
            'page_attachment_basic',
            'page_attachment_full_width_link',
            'page_attachment_slideshow',
            'page_attachment_tabs',
            'page_attachment_three_column'
        );


        // Get the entity type of the row content.
        $row_type = $vars['row']->_entity_properties['entity object']->type;
        // Check to see if the type is in the above array of page attachments and that
        // referencing entity is populated. If not then this content isn't being used on
        // any pages.
        if(in_array($row_type, $content_types) && array_key_exists('referencing_entity', $vars['row']->_entity_properties['entity object']) == TRUE) {
            // Query the page attachment table for the referencing entity.
            $query = db_query('SELECT entity_id
                FROM field_data_field_page_attachments
                WHERE bundle IN (:type)
                    AND field_page_attachments_value = :nid', array(
                        ':type' => array('second_level_page', 'network'),
                        ':nid' => $vars['row']->_entity_properties['entity object']->referencing_entity->item_id
            ))->fetchAssoc();

            // load the entity
            $parent_nid = $query['entity_id'];
            $parent_node = node_load($parent_nid);

            // get the path alias for the content.
            $parent_node_url = drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $parent_node->nid);
            global $base_path;
            $parent_node_url = $base_path . $parent_node_url;

            // Rewrite the url to point to the referencing entity.
            $pattern = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
            $vars['fields']['title']->content = preg_replace($pattern, $parent_node_url, $vars['fields']['title']->content);
            $vars['fields']['view_node']->content = preg_replace($pattern, $parent_node_url, $vars['fields']['view_node']->content);
        }

        switch($vars['fields']['type']->content) {
            case '<span class="field-content">Second Level Page</span>':
                $vars['fields']['type']->content = '<span class="field-content">Page</span>';
                break;
            case '<span class="field-content">Blog entry</span>':
                $vars['fields']['type']->content = '<span class="field-content">Blog</span>';
                break;
            case '<span class="field-content">Page Attachment - Tabs</span>':
                $vars['fields']['type']->content = '<span class="field-content">Page</span>';
                break;
            case '<span class="field-content">Product</span>':
                $vars['fields']['type']->content = '<span class="field-content">Publication</span>';
                break;
            case '<span class="field-content">Project</span>':
                $vars['fields']['type']->content = '<span class="field-content">Network Project</span>';
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when we have the view set up to use ajax and auto submit for the exposed filters the preprocess seems to only run for the first load and then the ajax responses of filtered content seem to skip the preprocess function.

Comment: It seems like after execution of your preprocess function first time, the data gets cached and that's why ajax might not get loaded properly. So one way is to make this view cache false, or use hook_exit() to perform cleanup tasks at the end and if still issue exists, write your own js using ` Drupal.behaviors.myViewsRefresh`

Comment: It's not the ajax that doesn't get loaded but the content doesn't run through the HOOK_preprocess_views_view_fields() for the field templates again when returning an ajax refresh of the view.